# How does this voltage-reference circuit works

Tags: operational-amplifier, zener, voltage-reference

[image: voltage reference circuit]

I have been trying to understand how this circuit works for the past few hours, it is supposed to be a voltage reference circuit that uses a zener diode, I am supposed to derive an expression for Vout given a Vz, I dont know if it there is supposed to be a current going through R4. Can somebody help me please.

Comment: Operational amplifier tends to keep 0V between IN+ and IN-. So voltage on R3 equal V2.

Comment: "I dont know if it there is supposed to be a current going through R4." As a first order approximation, current into or out of the differential inputs is 0. Of course it is not 0, but in this case, your other currents are large enough that you can ignore the current through R4. Question, if there is no current through R4, what will be the voltage drop across it? What then will be the voltage at the op amp's non-inverting input?

Answer (score 1):

For a DC analysis you can ignore R4 and C1 since an ideal op-amp has no bias current and the capacitor is not important at DC.

You should be able to calculate the output voltage assuming that the zener is conducting, and then calculate the zener current. Assume the op-amp drives its inputs to be equal as hinted in the comments.

This circuit  has a potential problem. With a bipolar supply it has two stable states. With a supply as shown it also **may**  have two stable states depending on a few non-ideal things.

Answer (score 1):

On opamp out:
Vout = K(Vp-Vn),

Vp = V2, because leakage current too small

Vn = Vout* R3/(R2 + R3).

Vout = K* V2 - Vout* K* R3/(R2 + R3) => Vout = V2* K/(1 + K* R3/(R2 + R3)).

R4-C1 is lowpass filter for circuit stability.

Load current must be less than opamp max current minus stabilitron current and resistive divider current.

Comment: FYI, we usually we try to avoid giving people the answer when it is a homework question. We try to help them figure out the answer by asking key questions or giving hints. I am not "in charge" and you are not "in trouble." I am just sharing what the convention is here since you seem to be new and I am hoping you will stick around.

Comment: I got it, thank you guys so much.